# CSS how to place column

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

How to place the columns horizontally using css.

How should be:

[image]

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      First element column 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       Second element column 1
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
        First element column 2
    </td>
    <td>
        First element column 3
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
        Second element column 2
    </td>
    <td>
        Second element column 3
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I cannot change markup because all tags is the product of :

```
@foreach(var computer in department.Computers)
{
  <tr >
      <td>
              @computer.ID
      </td>
  </tr>
}

@foreach (var employee in department.Employees)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @employee.Text
        </td>
        <td>
            @employee.Number
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use Bootstrap section table (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-tables). Take a look at col-md-X (where X is a number). If you don't want to use bootstrap maybe you could take a look at classes and take what you exactly want.

Comment: I cannot place div before tr inside table tag. It's main problem. Visual studio does not allow.

Comment: Something I don't understand - why you just can't change markup? Is it autogenerated?

Comment: @A191919 What language are you using for the loop? Also, what does your array look like?

Comment: @user3284463, i am using asp.net mvc

Comment: @A191919 did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <table>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                            First element column 1
                    </td>
               
                <td>
                        First element column 2
                </td>
           
                    <td>
                        First element column 3
                    </td>
                   
                </tr>

            <tr>
 <td>
                        Second element column 1
                    </td>
                <td>
                    Second element column 2
                </td>
                <td>
                    Second element column 3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace first `</tr>` and put second from foreach bounds.

```
 <tr >
@foreach(var computer in department.Computers)
     {

        <td>
             @computer.ID
        </td>
        @foreach (var employee in department.Employees)
         {

                        <td>
                            @employee.Text
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @employee.Number
                        </td>

          }                          
   }              
  </tr>
```

Something like this